# Adding a new comment to Jira via the command line

Tags: rest, curl, jira

I had a hunt for this all over the place and found a few resources that had a lack of decent examples such as [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp2011456), [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1602) and [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Updating+an+Issue+via+the+JIRA+REST+APIs).

The most helpful was [this one](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/87692/does-jira-5-1-4-rest-api-2-support-put-method). which gave the following:

```
curl -D- -u myname:mypassword -X PUT -d "{\"fields\":{\"summary\":\"My title thru Curl\"}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:portnum/jira/rest/api/2/issue/Issue-4
```

How can I add a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
curl -D- -u uname:pass -X PUT -d "{\"update\": {\"comment\": [{\"add\": {\"body\": \"Comment added when resolving issue\"}}]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-12345
```

I've added a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/TheMightyLlama/9427202) which gives a couple of use cases

Comment: how can i add comments in jira with user name ?

Comment: @SureshKumarAmrani replace `uname` and `pass` with the credentials of the user who needs to make the comment. Presumably you.

Answer (score 1):

I found another option that is just adding a new comment without modifying the issue itself (it might be good when the user doesn't have rights to edit but only to comment).

```
curl -D- -u uname:pass -X PUT -d "{\"body\": \"Comment added when resolving issue\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira-server:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-12345/comment
```

You should just receive a response with a status of "201" with the full json representation of the added comment.

It's well documented now in https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-add-comment